# Fatal error: Class 'JFactory' not found in joomla 3.3

Tags: php, joomla

3
I have a form I developed on my site but out of joomla structure.
on the form, I am trying to call active user data like so:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
echo "<p>Your name is {$user->name}, your email is {$user->email}, and your username is  {$user->username}</p>";
```

but I am getting:
Fatal error: Class 'JFactory' not found in /home5/onlinepc/public_html/action/subs/custompcorder.php on line 38

custompcorder.php is the name of the form I created line 38 is $user = JFactory::getUser();
I guest I have to include something on my file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to import the Joomla library to be able to use it's API, like so:

```
<?php
    define('_JEXEC', 1);
    define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../'));  
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
?>
```

You may need to change the path on line 2 of the code above depending on where Joomla is located in relation to your custom PHP file.

Comment: I am having a hard time including the directory path. my custom php file is located in `Public/action/subs/custompcorder.php` defines.php and framework.php are located in: `Public/includes/defines.php` and `Public/includes/framework.php`  my settings is taking me each time to `Public/action/subs/includes/framework.php

Comment: @user3412978 - I have updated the code accordingly. It should work now